# Vincular PHP con Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hola vincule la PHP  con MySql pero me sale este error :

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\doblea\BD.php:15 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\doblea\conexion.php(4): conectar() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\doblea\BD.php on line 15

Que puedo hacer ?

Comment: Por favor añade tu código para poderte ayudar. Por ahora solo puedo ver que estás usando la extensión mysql obsoleta y eliminada de PHP.

Comment: archivo : BD.php  <?php

function  conectar()

{
    $user = "root@localhost";
    // root es usuario por default
    $pass ="";
    //la contraseña
    $server = "localHost";
    //declarar servidor
    $db ="doblea";
    //nombre de la BD
    $con = mysql_connect($server,$user,$pass) or die("Error al conectar BD".mysql_error());
    //variable conexion a la BD
    mysql_select_db($db,$con);
    //seleccionamos que BD vamos a usar
    return $con;
}
?>    archivo conexion.php <?php
include("BD.php");
$con = conectar();
echo "se realiza la con con la BD";
?>

Comment: Hola, por favor edita tu pregunta y pega tu código ahí. Puedes darle formato con el botón `{}`. También te recomiendo visitar la página [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que sea más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: `<?php
include("BD.php");

$con = conectar();
echo "se realiza la con con la BD";

?>`

Comment: <?php

function  conectar()

{
    //5 variables
    $user = "root@localhost";
    // root es usuario por default
    $pass ="";
    //la contraseña
    $server = "localHost";
    //declarar servidor
    $db ="doblea";
    //nombre de la BD
    $con = mysql_connect($server,$user,$pass) or die("Error al conectar BD".mysql_error());
    //variable conexion a la BD
    mysql_select_db($db,$con);
    //seleccionamos que BD vamos a usar

    return $con;
}

?>